The Duhem-Quine thesis was extended by Quine. Can it be extended even further?
On the issue of Underdetermination, the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy mentions that
“Quine suggested that such challenges applied not only to the confirmation of all types of scientific theories, but to all knowledge claims”.
Without consulting the author, I assume that the knowledge claims which would fall under this category were about such knowledge that could be deducted from facts in a similar manner as the scientific knowledge relating to the original Duhem-Quine thesis, i.e. reasonably deduced knowledge.
I now wonder if one might expand this a step further – referring to the same principle of underdetermination  -  saying that it also applies to the meaning of statements? That would point to one aspect, namely that the context or framework in which the statement is made can vary, so as to allow for a variety of interpretations , making an absolutely  clear statement impossible.

Yes, Duhem-Quine is almost infinitely extendable.  All thigs we think we know, are only known because of supporting evidence.  And every "known" thing could in principle be replaced with an infinity of more complex "facts" that reduces to what we think we know as a special case.

You should really consult the author, because denying that scientific knowledge can be deduced from "facts" is one of those things he is famous for. And he literally wrote a book on underdetermination of meaning, Word and Object. His term for it is indeterminacy of translation.

Quine literally argues exactly that in the second section of Two Dogmas.

The idea of defining a symbol in use was, as remarked, an advance over the impossible term-by-term empiricism of Locke and Hume. The statement, rather than the term, came with Frege to be recognized as the unit accountable to an empiricist critique.
But what I am now urging is that even in taking the statement as unit we have drawn our grid too finely. The unit of empirical significance is the whole of science.

But I do not think it is correct.

Curious to know what you are thinking of the idea.

@ScottRowe He's thinking you can get Two Hotdogmas at Costco for only $3! Quine would have appreciated that frugality.

@ScottRowe A host of issues. First that sentences in natural language do not get their meaning from their Truth Evaluation condition. Contrast Chomsky, "The autonomy of syntax" vs Quine, "Logic chasses Truth up the tree of grammar." Therefore syntax is not something you decide but naturally possess. Second consequently NLS is not subject to revision as opposed to scientific statements.

Ok. I just thought that your post, after saying you don't think it is correct, could add what you do think. Cheers!

You say:

I now wonder if one might expand this a step further – referring to the same principle of underdetermination - saying that it also applies to the meaning of statements.

As Conifold has mentioned, Quine has a famous text about gavagai and rabbits. He uses the word gavagai to illustrate how even a linguist might struggle to translate a completely unknown language. He suggests we imagine a linguist observing a native speaker who says gavagai upon seeing a rabbit. The linguist might translate this as "rabbit" but other translations like "food", "Let’s go hunting", or even "undetached rabbit part" could also fit the observed behavior.
In Word and Object, he tackles all sorts of philosophy of language issues such as vagueness, predication, synonymy, and referential opacity, and has a section on the semantics of proposition. Ultimately where he lands is the radical indetermination of translation (IEP), confirmation holism, and Neurath's boat and so on, though he walked back some of that later on.
The core idea is that there is no unique, correct translation because multiple interpretations can be consistent with the same evidence. This leads to the conclusion that meaning and reference are inherently indeterminate, and he enters into relativistic themes with his inscrutability of reference and ontological relativity.
The big picture is that Quine fundamentally challenges the idea that words are meaning bearers; later thinkers have moved in the direction that semantics is not "conveyed by meaning implicit to words and propositions" so much as inferred by speakers from contexts, a point covered in detail in relevance theory. For instance, Grice coined the implicature/explicature dichotomy. Urmson and Hirsch have fleshed out additional ideas like quantifier variance where it is a central that no natural language is special in regards to "carving up reality at the joints".
This way moves in the opposite direction of the thinking of logical atomism (with it's strong roots in analyticity and positivism) which is committed to a correspondence theory of truth where magical powers are attached to the idea that syntactic primitives reflect some privileged role in speaking about a single, objective reality. Today, much thinking about meaning has graduated from the traditional notions of syntax and semantics, such as early speculation about deep structure as mirroring the surface structure of a language and guiding transformations, and moved questions of meaning into pragmatics.
So, Quine's attack on the synthetic/analytic divide helped move the linguistic turn from the thinking of early Wittgenstein to late Wittgenstein who recognized that in a Sprachspiel, it is intention and intentionality that matters. Quine is instrumental in showing that meaning bearers are more than just deductively certain codes, but are participatory in a broader notion that meaning must be inferred, interpreted, and constructed by the hearer based on experience and context. At the end of Word and Object, Quine says:

[W]e do recognize a shift from talk of objects to talk of words as debate professes from existence of wombats and unicorns to existence of points, miles, classes, and the rest. How can we account for this? Amply, I think, by proper account of a useful and much used manoeuvre which I shall call semantic ascent.

Thus, following up on Carnap's ontological thinking, and moving against it, Quine recognizes that semantic ascent is an important part not just of metaphysical discourse, but of all discourse. Like Carnap, he recognizes that language itself reflects the need to negotiate ontological commitment between two agents. Thus grammars are shown to be less important to meaning than shared intentionality.
Later Richard Rorty takes Quine's thesis and attacks analytic philosophy in Philosophy and the Mirror of Nature by looking at analytic philosophy as a whole as engaged in a silly game with pseudo-problems created by language and as inspired by the pragmatism of Dewey to move away from representationalism and truth-conditional semantics as the goal of philosophy generally. Here, we can see a post-positivist attitude towards claims of objectivity rooted in the objectivity of observation, language, and the correspondent theory of truth itself. In this way Quine, helped motivate some philosophers to move towards a picture of thinking more in line with the tradition of Continental phenomenology.
